# Setting up Nhibernate mapping by code session factory with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I am trying to setup a Session factory with Nhibernate code by mapping, but I have issues configuring it, and its pretty hard to find guides to Code by mapping with the session factory.

Atm. I have this SessionManager, but I am uncertain where to specify its a MySQL database, proberly miss more.

```
public class SessionManager
{
    private const string ConnString = "Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=test; Uid=root; Pwd=123456;";

    public static SessionManager CurrentInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentInstance == null)
            {
                object sync = new object();
                lock (sync)
                    _currentInstance = new SessionManager();
            }
            return _currentInstance;
        }
    }

    public static ISession Session
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                object sync = new object();
                lock (sync)
                    _sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                        .DataBaseIntegration(x => x.ConnectionString = ConnString)
                        .Configure()
                        .AddAssembly(typeof(EmployeeMap).Assembly)
                        .BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
    }

    private SessionManager() { }

    static SessionManager _currentInstance;
    static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is specify that you are using mysql. When I have done this I have used an NHibernate confiuration file with a line stating the driver_class:

`<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>`

Try this tutorial

http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx

it describes the process of setting up your nhibernate session and shows a sample hibernate.cfg.xml file. In this set up you need to specify the MySqlDataDriver instead of the SQLServerCeDriver shown.

I don't know if you can do this without having to use a hibernate.cfg.xml